# .Net MAUI How to Detect ThemeChanged Real-Time?

Tags: maui

To clarify the question.
I want to ask that how can I detect ThemeChanged while the application is running and can I change the color properties at CodeBehind C#.
I think there needs to be something like a Real-Time system to always listen when the Device changes the subject. I looked into SignalR, but it requires a server.. Looks like SignalR is for bigger problems than ThemeChanged Detection.

Specifically I have some CodeBehind code that will change colors based on the current Theme the App is running on.

```
AppTheme currenttheme = (AppTheme)Application.Current.RequestedTheme;
if (currenttheme is AppTheme.Dark)
{
    yellow = FontsVip.Yellow;
    pink = FontsVip.PinkCode;
    red = FontsVip.RedCode;
    blue = FontsVip.BlueCode;
    green = FontsVip.GreenCode;
    body = FontsVip.BodyCode;
}
else
{
    yellow = FontsVip.LYellow;
    pink = FontsVip.LPinkCode;
    red = FontsVip.LRedCode;
    blue = FontsVip.LBlueCode;
    green = FontsVip.LGreenCode;
    body = FontsVip.LBodyCode;
}
//Set Default Color
Questioncolor = Checkcolor = red;
Eyecolor = yellow;
```

But these codes only run once in the Constructor or if I assign it to a Button or a specific action...

The problem is that I need to Detect when a Device/User intentionally changes its theme while the application is running. And then I will be able to activate the scripts..

If you have a better way please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to detect ThemeChanged Real-Time:

```
Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, a) =>
{
    // Respond to the theme change
};
```

For more information, you can refer to the official document about [React to theme changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: The code works fine. What advice do you have? Or where should I put this code so that my App can always detect ThemeChanged Real-Time from the moment I open the app until I close it? (Because currently I always put it in Contructors or after the Page is initialized).

Comment: You can put it in the App class's Contructors. @HưngNguyễn